# url_title Does Not Return Results in {exp:playa:parents} Tag

Tags: playa, filter

I'm trying to filter a list of products based off of a Playa field. The URL for the template is like this: `http://www.mysite.com/products/seller/joes-jetpacks`

`joes-jetpacks` is the URL Title of the entry the product is related to. So to display all products that are sold by Joe's Jetpacks, I'm using this tag:

```
{exp:playa:parents
    channel='products'
    url_title='{segment_3}'
    limit='7'
    disable='member_data|category_fields'
    orderby='title'
    sort='asc'
    paginate='both'
    status='open|Featured'
}
    {!-- channel listing content --}
{/exp:playa:parents}
```

But that returns no results. Alternately, if I replace the `url_title` parameter with `entry_id`, and use the url `http://www.mysite.com/products/seller/1234` instead, I get the correct results.

- EE 2.5.2
- Playa 4.4.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, Playa is doing everything correct here. The parameters you pass on `{exp:playa:parents}` are for defining what *parent* entries you want to get; they’re not meant to describe the *child*, which is what you’re doing with `url_title`.

If you have a URL Title for an entry and you want to get the parents of that entry, you first have to get the child entry with `{exp:channel:entries}`:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="merchants"
                     url_title="{segment_3}"
                     limit="1"
                     disable="categories|custom_fields|member_data|pagination"}

    {exp:playa:parents channel='products'
                       limit='7'
                       disable='member_data|category_fields'
                       orderby='title'
                       sort='asc'
                       paginate='both'
                       status='open|Featured'}

        {!-- channel listing content --}

    {/exp:playa:parents}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Makes sense. I think I just got confused because `entry_id` worked, and I'm used to the two being interchangeable as far as functionality.

Comment: Ah yes. `entry_id` is the one exception to that, which does target the child entry ID.